# What prevents me from reversing a hash function?

Tags: hash, cryptography, md5, sha

What actually prevents me from reversing a hash function and generating a possible input from a hash that will have the same hash?

I understand that hash functions are one-way functions, which means I cannot recover the **real** input by it's hash.

I googled it a lot, and I found out a lot of peoples explaining this simple example hash function:

```
hash(x) = x % 7
```

I can't recover the input (x) from the hash here, but if I know the hash, I can generate a **possible input** from it that will have the same hash:

```
unhash(h) = some_random_integer * 7 + h
```

The value of `some_random_integer` does not matter at all. unhash(3) will be for example: 24 , and hash(24) is: 3 !

One more example that I found is:

```
hash(x, y) = x * y
```

So like the previous example, I cannot find the real input (x and y) from the hash but I can find a **possible input** that will have the same hash:

```
x = hash / some_random_integer
y = hash / x
```

When for example, a malicious hacker gains access to a database full of hashed passwords, he would be able to log in to a hacked user only by generating a **possible input** that will generate the same hash as his password! It does not have to be the exact original password.

I know that real hash functions are a lot more complicated than this examples, but I cannot think of a math operation that cannot be reversed this way. (or maybe there are some?)

What actually prevents me from reversing real hash functions this way? (like MD5, SHA1, etc...)

Comment: Because cryptographically sound hash functions are engineered to be very difficult to find an alias input.

Comment: This question should be moved to https://crypto.stackexchange.com/

Comment: As you said, it's not impossible, it's just very very difficult.  Properly hashed and salted passwords (using a proper password hashing algorithm) would take so long to find a match it's not possible to do in realistic time frames, even though it would be theoretically possible to break giving infinite time.

Comment: @wallyk I understand that, but my question is how is it done?

Comment: @puhlen I'm not talking about brute force, I'm talking about just reversing the algorithm. (What can take so much time in it?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about programming. [It's been asked before on Cryptography](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/9/what-is-the-general-justification-for-the-hardness-of-finding-preimages-for-cryp).

Comment: If the password hashing is an iteration consuming about 100ms of CPU timer reversing, if possible, would take a comparable amount of time. But generally some information is intentionally lost so reversing is not an option. One opertion that looses information is `mod`, another is integer overflow.

Comment: Here’s another answer for this question from crypto.se: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45377/why-cant-we-reverse-hashes

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [What are preimage resistance and collision resistance, and how can the lack thereof be exploited?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1173/10496) on the Crypto Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By hash function the assumption you are referring to cryptographic hash functions such as the SHA family.

The design of the cryptographic hash function keeps you from reversing it, that is the basic criteria in the design.

There are other types of hash functions such as dictionary hash functions that may be quite simple but even these but usually lose portions of the input. `hash(x) = x % 7` is an example of such a simple hash function.

In the case of password hashing brute forcing must be taken into account, that is trying passwords from lists of frequently used passwords and fuzzing. The usual solution is to use a hash function that consumes substantial CPU time, ofter by iteration a hash function for about 100ms, [PBKFD2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is such a function and is recommended by NIST for password hashing.

Additionally the input may be larger than the output= and some information is intentionally lost.